# How to add vertical button using bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-grid

How to add vertical button using bootstrap .

[image]

Comment: Look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892223/using-css-to-rotate-an-inputs-value-90-degrees

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CSS to rotate an input's value 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892223/using-css-to-rotate-an-inputs-value-90-degrees)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use CSS to rotate the text inside of the button.

```
# CSS file

.rotate {

    /* Safari */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

}
```

Comment: also transform: rotate(-90deg); for all.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.btn {
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

**Working JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/t0sjtewo/